# link_to a controller's index regardless of the page

Tags: ruby, indexing, controller, root, link-to

I'm rendering a header with links to various controllers in the `application` file

The path that `link_to` uses seems to be relative to the current page, and it just directs to the current URL minus one instance of a forward slash. This doesn't work if you're any level deeper than first one.

For instance, clicking a link to the `posts` controller works while you're on `posts#index`, but being on `posts/1` directs you to `posts/posts`

Have routes got anything to do with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just rectified this problem by adding a forward slash before the destination.

```
link_to "posts", "/posts"
```